# Switch slave to new master

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

I have one master and 2 slaves in a mysql replication mode. All slaves are synchronised to the actual master.
Because of space disk problem, I have to shutdown master_old to switch the first slave to be the new master. And slave 2 in replication mode with the new master.

So, I have to stop master_old, reset slave one, switch with a master conf the slave1, and restart mysql to generate binlog etc.

But do I need to make a dump of the new master for the slave2? Can I restart slave2 with a simple reset slave and change master host with log pos of master_old to the new one ?

thanks

Comment: Be sure to stop all writes to the system during the tasks.

Comment: Yes. Master will be stopped. But should I let the new master generate a binlog before starting replication, or can I restart the second slave on the new master with the pos log of the old slave?

Comment: Are you using GTIDs or binlog positioning?